Error : The remote server returned an error : (404) Not found when using Copy-PnPFolder powershell
I have been using the  Copy-PnPFolder to copy files between sharepoint sites.
But just suddenly i started receiding this error
: The remote server returned an error : (404) Not found

This is how i connect
Connet-PnPOnline - Url https://Source-SharePointOnline.com - interactive (Source Site)
Connet-PnPOnline - Url https://Destination-SharePointOnline.com - interactive  (Destination Site)

Copy-PnPFolder -SourceUrl "/Shared Documents/Corporate/09 - BD & Marketing/Test" -TargetUrl "/sites/MarketingTeam/Marketing" -Overwrite

Any ideas what i'mmissing here.
THanks in Advance

Source and target sites must be on the same tenant, so on the same subdomain.sharepoint.com. Is it correct for your use case?

Yes and thanks. Somehow its all good. Not sure what went wrong.
It was very strange
